# GroupBy with two parameters in Laravel with nested relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a challenge that I can't solve. My context:

I have this models:

- User `{id, ...}`
- Owner `{id, ...}`
- Contact `{id, product_id, owner_id, message_id}`
- Product `{id, ...}`
- Message `{id, user_id, message}`

Relations:

- Owner has many Contacts.
- Contact belong to one Owner
- Contact belong to one Product
- Contact belong to one Message
- Message belongs to User

Then my goal is that when I call `$owner->contacts`, I want a groupBy `contact.product_id` and `contact.message.user_id`, because a product can has messages from differents users.
Desired output:

```
    [
    {
        product_id: "2",
        messages: [
        {
            message_id: "23",
            user_id: "13",
            message: "...."    
        },
        {
            message_id: "53",
            user_id: "13",
            message: "...."    
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        product_id: "2",
        messages: [
        {
            message_id: "3",
            user_id: "9",
            message: "...."    
        },
        {
            message_id: "5",
            user_id: "9",
            message: "...."    
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

My purpose is to make the owner's profile page, in the contacts section, show a list with all the contacts that he has by product from different users and within this contact group all the messages received by that product from the same user.

Comment: If `Onwer::with(['contacts.product.messages'])->find($ownerId);` all product's messages are all together.
       `[{ product_id: "2", messages: [ all of them] } ]`
What do you want to do with that data next? What's the purpouse of having then groupped by product? Maybe you could start from another model, like messages where has product where... (add the rest of the query)

Comment: @Filip I'll try this. My purpose is to make the owner's profile page, in the contacts section, show a list with all the contacts that he has by product from different users and within this contact group all the messages received by that product from the same user.